# Regex issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Just like the title I have an issue with the following code

```js
function checkPhone(phone){
    var reg = "/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im";
    var result=phone.match(reg);
    if (result) {
        console.log("(true)phone  "+phone);
        return (true)
    } else {
        console.log("(error)phone "+phone);

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label >Numero di Telefono</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="phone" onchange="checkPhone(this.value)" placeholder="Insert phone number">
</div>
```

Regardless of what I try to put in `phone`, it will result in `"(error)phone "+phone`. I have also tried it online and it works.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Drop the quotation marks in `reg`, a regex pattern is not a string in js

Comment: It may have something to do with the change event. Every time you type a character the event will fire and, if what is currently in the value for that input doesn't match the regex, you will get your error. You may want to look at the `pattern` attribute of the [`<input type="tel">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#pattern) element for better validation.

Comment: @Andy i tried this way and nothing happened,it just changed the input type but still error

Comment: You should add some examples of the numbers you want to be matched to your question so we can test the regex. @ChristianMascolo. Not _actual_ phone numbers of people you know, made up ones :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have quotes around the regular expression. Try this:

```js
function checkPhone(phone){
    var reg = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
    var result=phone.match(reg);
    if (result) {
        console.log("(true)phone  "+phone);
        return (true)
    } else {
        console.log("(error)phone "+phone);

    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label >Numero di Telefono</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="phone" onchange="checkPhone(this.value)" placeholder="Insert phone number">
</div>
```

See [Regular Expressions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: There is more wrong with it than just that - did you test this? It still `(error)phone 123`

Comment: Just tried this way and it finally work.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CanO'Spam, seems to work for me when I put in an actual 10 digit number. Your "123" isn't a phone number so it's going to say it's an error.

Comment: @CanO'Spam I did try it with multiple valid and invalid phone numbers, using the exact same regular expression. The regular expression is also the same as the one found on iHateRegex.io, which has been proven to work. Next time, please try it with a valid phone number. "123" is not valid.

Comment: My comment was a me issue, I do apologise, copy/paste error into a html file locally (and used a 3-3-4 number to test)